# How to route domain to elastickbeanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have running app in elastickbeanstalk on domain:
`secret-development.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com`

And I would like to route my domain into this app.

I created CNAME `www` to `secret-development.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com`

But it is not working.

What is wrong?

Comment: "But it is not working." - can you explain why its not working? Any errors, timeouts, unexpected behavior, ...?

Comment: I am getting (in chrome) This site can’t be reached DOMAIN**s server IP address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I created CNAME `www` to `secret-development.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com`

Unfortunately, you **can't create** working `www` CNAME record to the default EB domain. The reason is that this is **AWS owned domain** and you have no control over it.

If you don't want to use AWS provided domain for you EB environment, you have to create/buy **your own domain**, e.g. `mydomain.com`. This can be done in [Route53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-register.html), but can also use any other domain seller.

How to use Route53 to setup a custom domain for EB is explained in the following AWS documentation:

- [Creating an Amazon Route 53 record that routes traffic to your Elastic Beanstalk environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-beanstalk-environment.html#routing-to-beanstalk-environment-create-resource-record-set)

If you have your own domain (e.g., `mydomain.com`), then you can also setup a subdomain (`www.mydomain.com`) for it and point it to EB environment.

Having your own domain will also enable you to setup `https` to your EB environment.

Comment: I have my domain routed to cloudflare system. And from this system I can set up A, AAAA, CNAME, etc.. to elastickbeanstalk. Which record should I use ?

Comment: You should be creating a CNAME record for `www` to `secret-development.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com` as you described. Make sure to set the initial TTL to something low, like 60 or 300s. Then you can use a site like https://www.whatsmydns.net/ to check the propagation.  If you can see that it has propagated but is still not working I would contact AWS or Cloudflare support.

Comment: @masiyik879 Please refresh and remove all caches from browsers. Also it takes some time for domains to propagate.

Comment: Hi @Marcin finaly, cname is ready (tested by whatsmydns.net). But I am getting `504 Gateway Time-out`. Any suggestion? It is running on port 80, so it is same for cname.

I can open cname alias (`secret-development.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com`) and it is working correctly. I have cname `test` for `secret-development.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com`. Once I open `test.mydomain.com` I am getting 504 gateway err :-/ Also I can see 504 on my loadbalencer

Comment: @masiyik879 Is it all setup in Route53?

Comment: Nope, I am using my provider, I only set cname `test` to `secret-development.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com. Once I open test.mydomain.com `

Comment: @masiyik879 Domain propagation takes some time. ALso make sure to refresh or clear your browser cache.

Comment: I set it before two days, I am using anonymous window, also its ready on `whatsmydns.net` so, propagation is done.

Comment: But when you just go to `secret-development.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com` it all works as expected? Do you have any custom listener rules your ALB?

Comment: Ok, it is working, but there is something wrong with my root file.. Looks like a problem in my app.

Comment: @masiyik879 Thanks and glad to hear. Seems like a new issue. May considered making new question with new details relevant to the root file.